# how to merge from feature branch to the master branch using bitbucket-pipeline.yml file?

Tags: version-control, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

Working using feature branches, how can i configure my bitbucket-pipeline.yml file in such a way that the changes are merged to the master branch automatically?

Comment: Please specify SCM system you're using in tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've done to get a branch merged in master

```
#fetch from all branches and mock a user to perform the merge
- git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
  \ && git config user.email "git@example.com"
  \ && git config user.name "git"
- git fetch origin && git checkout origin/master
- git merge $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
```

Finally, if you want to commit the merge, you should add a `git push` command at the end of the script, likely using a real account for the repository.

**EDIT**

The above solution seems to work only when the user is the owner of the repository.
Try using the [`depth`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_depthdepth) option for the pipeline configuration as stated [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13798/grant-a-git-read-only-access-to-current#comment-34108284), to clone the full repository.

Comment: Not working for me, its showing nothing-to-update